# Adding numeric value to a number type column with existing value in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would like to ask how can I add a value (int or decimal type) to an column (with the same type) that has an existing value.

If I will use java, I could easily say:

```
int load_balance = 1250;
load_balance += 75;
```

But, how do I properly do this in Hibernate?

Would it be?

1. Get current load_balance value
2. Add the_amount to the current load_balance value.
3. Save or update load_balance.

Not sure what would be the best hibernate practice for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this thing by using setter method like below :

```
@Table(name = "SAMPLE")
public class Entity {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "LOAD_NUMBER")
    private Integer loadNumber;

    @Column(name = "LOAD_BALANCE")
    private Double loadBalance;

    public void setLoadNumber(Integer loadNumber) {
        int prev = this.loadNumber != null ? this.loadNumber : 0;
        this.loadNumber = prev + loadNumber;
    }

    public void setLoadBalance(Double loadBalance) {
        double prev = this.loadBalance != null ? this.loadBalance : 0.0;
        this.loadBalance = prev + loadBalance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HQL for that. For an example, if you have an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_balances")
public class Balance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "f_pid")
    private Long pid;

    @Column(name = "f_load_balance")
    private Integer loadBalance;

}
```

Corresponding HQL to update `loadBalance`

```
String query = "update Balance set loadBalance = loadBalance + 1 where pid = :balancePid";

Query query = session.createQuery(query);
query.setParameter("balancePid", balancePid);
query.executeUpdate();
```

It is converted to the similar SQL and executed by database. It is a bit faster than `session.update()` because of you don't need to load `Balance` persistent. But, I think, for one record it doesn't matter (and it can be slower because of random effects, caches etc.).

Comment: would it be like I am just running an executeUpdate? would this be faster than session.update ?